# How to access Blazor app on LInux (Centos)

Tags: .net, linux, blazor

I am trying to access a Blazor webassembly app on a Linux server. I have completed all the necessary Linux side installations for .NET and I have created a test Blazor app. When I try to access this from a browser I get a "This site can’t be reached". The web server on this server is accessible using other apps written in Python and PHP. I have performed all the necessary firewall settings for the appropriate ports. I know .Net on linux uses the Kestrel web server. Can Kestrel service public web page requests?

Can anyone give me any pointers as to what I need to consider next? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"a Blazor webassembly app" can be hosted as a bunch of static files. So,

> I have completed all the necessary Linux side installations for .NET

wasn't necessary at all.

Check your config, can you download a simple file, eg site.css with a Browser?   If not, what do the dev tools tell you?

And of course, check your Server's logs.

Comment: Thank you Henk. DOH! seems so obvious now as it is the browser that will interpret the downloaded files. I think I have been following instructions to install the .NET SDK - to enable development on the linux box! Thanks again.